# Hide linked series on legend hover in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

According to http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line, by linking two series, "Toggling the visibility of this also toggles the linked series".

When linking two series, I expect them to both be activated when hovering a legend item. This does not work with this setup

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  title: { text: 'Linked Series'},
  series: [{
    id: 2,
    data: [3, 1, 3, 2]
  }, {
    id: 0,
    data: [2, 3, 2, 1]
  }, {
    id: 1,
    linkedTo: 2,
    data: [1, 2, 1, 3]
  }, ]
});
```

How can I make sure, that all linked series are hovered at the same time.

https://fiddle.jshell.net/papa_bravo/oxbm6mke/

Comment: It was reported some time ago and labeled as enhancement, so there is a change this improvement appear in future releases: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4521.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a small bug in Highcharts; if `id`s are numbers then turning off the visibility by clicking the legend does not work properly. If you convert `id`s to stings it works OK

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  title: { text: 'Linked Series'},
  series: [{
    id: '2',
    data: [3, 1, 3, 2]
  }, {
    id: '0',
    data: [2, 3, 2, 1]
  }, {
    id: '1',
    linkedTo: '2',
    data: [1, 2, 1, 3]
  }, ]
});
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/oxbm6mke/6/

**EDIT:** Actually it's not a bug. According to the [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.linkedTo) `linkedTo` must be a string.